# Can anyone indentify this SMD component?

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I'm trying to identifiy this component. I assume that it must be some kind of mosfet or bjt. Can someone point me to a Manufacturer Part number or datasheet?

The component is used in the circuit to blow a fuse. Its basicaly a 1-bit memory to permanently store an error condition.
[image: SMD component]
[image]

Comment: Could the surrounding circuitry make a *thyristor* a possibility? What is driving it? Eg: [BT151](https://www.rapidonline.com/pdf/151290_da_en_01.pdf)

Comment: Yes, i think thats a possibility. Its driven by a comparator that detects overtemperatures.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this will be a simple Thyristor in a DPAK type package.

The [BT151S-500](http://www.ween-semi.com/documents/BT151S_SER_L_R.pdf) from WeEn-Semi (now part of NXP) matches the package (SOT428/DPAK), and also the partial part number (151S5).

[image: Snippet from Datasheet]